# Need to create batch file to rename/number all files therein + 1

Tags: batch-file, rename, bulk

I apologize in advance - I'm very new to the world of batch files and I'm way over my head on this one.  I'm trying to make a simple (not so simple for me so far though haha) bulk renaming batch file where I take a folder with multiple randomly named files and rename and move all the files therein in a new folder in a very specific format.

The folder's format is always (name #) by default, and I'd like the first file to be renamed as the folder name, with the second file having the same name + 1.  So in a folder named zeta 24, the files get renamed in a new folder called zeta and the first file is zeta 24, second is zeta 25, and so on.  And finally, can i create a line pointing the exact location of the directories so I can run the batch file after I fill it with folders? I'm deathly afraid of renaming a folder that wasn't meant to be renamed, so I'm going to manually move these folders as needed into a directory for the batch file to look at.

Any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated, since I'm trying to learn all this on my own right now.  Thank you again!!!!

-Ben

Comment: What happens if you have directories named `zeta 25` with ten files and and `zeta 28` with ten files? You would want to create `zeta` but your filenames from `zeta 28` would clash with  `zeta 25..zeta 34` coming from `zeta 25`?

Comment: It's a good point, but it won't be an issue with the ordering system I'm working with.  All files corresponding to the subject (directory name) are put in that directory when they're entered, so fortunately there will never be two directories with the same subject name.  It's the files therein that need to have some sort of a sorting pattern so I can better organize this system.  Thank you for the thought though - you guys have helped me quite a bit!!

Answer (score 0):

### session example:

```
md "zeta 25"
for /l %a in (1 1 19) do @type nul>"zeta 25\test %a.txt"
dir /b "zeta 25"
```

output is:

```
test 1.txt
test 10.txt
test 11.txt
test 12.txt
test 13.txt
test 14.txt
test 15.txt
test 16.txt
test 17.txt
test 18.txt
test 19.txt
test 2.txt
test 3.txt
test 4.txt
test 5.txt
test 6.txt
test 7.txt
test 8.txt
test 9.txt
```

Batch code:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%a in (zeta*) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in ("%%~a") do set "newfolder=%%~b"&set /a base=%%c
    md "new\!newfolder!"
    for %%b in ("%%~a\*") do (
        move "%%~b" "new\!newfolder!\!newfolder! !base!%%~xb" >nul
        set /a base+=1
    )
)
dir /b "new\%newfolder%"
```

and output:

```
zeta 25.txt
zeta 26.txt
zeta 27.txt
zeta 28.txt
zeta 29.txt
zeta 30.txt
zeta 31.txt
zeta 32.txt
zeta 33.txt
zeta 34.txt
zeta 35.txt
zeta 36.txt
zeta 37.txt
zeta 38.txt
zeta 39.txt
zeta 40.txt
zeta 41.txt
zeta 42.txt
zeta 43.txt
```

Comment: Looks perfect - I'll give it a test run tonight and see if I can get it working!!!  You have me a little worried with the sequential ordering of the input filenames, since I (probably incorrectly) assumed the programming language running would look at it the same way as Windows.  In other words, I'm hoping it reads the files in order 1-10 as well as a-z instead of 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3 etc..  Either way, this is a great help to me - thank you for doing this, and so quickly at that :)

Comment: It would help if you were to clue us in on the filename structure.